# Is there a reverse logical nullish assignment?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, assignment-operator, nullish-coalescing

So the [nullish coalescing assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) `??=` assigns the value to the variable only if the current stored value is nullish.

Maybe I'm missing the obvious but I can't think of a slick solution (without if statements) to only assign if **the *right-hand side* value being assigned is not nullish**?

*I'm using nodeJS to give a bit more context*.

---

I want

```js
let x r??= 2;
// Updates 'x' to hold this new value
x r??= undefined;
// Has no effect, since the value to assign is nullish
console.log(x); // 2
```

**EDIT**
to give more clarity to my problem:

I want a variable only to be assigned a **new value**, if that new value is not nullish.

```js
let iceCream = {
    flavor: 'chocolate'
}

const foo = 2.5
const bar = undefined;

iceCream.price r??= bar
// does not assign the new value because it is nullish
console.log(iceCream.price) // expected to be error, no such property

iceCream.price r??= foo
// assigns the new value because it is not nullish but a float
console.log(iceCream.price) // expected to be 2.5

iceCream.price r??= bar
// does not assign the new value because it is nullish
console.log(iceCream.price) // expected to still be 2.5
```

Comment: Doesn't `x ??= undefined` already do exactly that?

Comment: @Ivar `x ?? = undefined` assigns `x` to undefined if `x` is nullish. OP wants to assign if `x` is **not** nullish.

Comment: @DanielBaldi: I think it’s if the *new* value is not nullish.

Comment: @Proxycon: Show the context where you’re going to use it for clarity and most appropriate alternatives?

Comment: @Ry- which new value you're referring to?

Comment: As I understand it (and as I think Ry is referring to), OP wants to set `x` to the right hand side operant, if the right hand side operant is not nullish (not when `x` is not nullish). Though my initial comment wont work, because it will still remain unmodified if both values are not nullish (if `x` is `2` and you use `x ??= 3`, it'll remain `2` instead of assigning `3`).

Comment: Regarding "_expected to be error, no such property_", note that accessing non-existing properties of an object doesn't throw errors. It just returns undefined. (Accessing properties of the `undefined` value/property however does throw errors.)

Comment: I believe you're looking for `x = newVal ?? x;`. Assigns `newVal` if `newVal` is anything except `null` or `undefined`, even falsy values (`0`, `NaN`, etc...). In all other cases, assigns `x`, which keeps it unchanged. For objects you can do `x.foo = newVal ?? x.foo;`, obviously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that’s not a single operator. The closest is two operators:

```js
x = undefined ?? x;
```

Comment: This comes close but does not work if I want to set a new property on an object.

Comment: @Proxycon: You need an `if` or a function wrapping one, then.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer after clarification as editing my previous one seemed weird.

The simplest way I can think of a solution without if is as follows:

```
let iceCream = {
    flavor: 'chocolate'
}

const foo = 2.5
const bar = undefined;
bar && (iceCream.price = bar)
// Another possible solution if creating the property with a nullish value is ok for you:
iceCream.price = bar || iceCream.price;
```

Comment: This is better than your other answer, but _non-nullish_ is not the same as 'truthy', and _nullish_ is not the same as 'falsy'. This distinction is **very** important to the question, since OP wants right-hand values such as `0`, `""` and `false` (which are evaluated as _falsy_) to be assigned.

Answer (score -2):

You could use [logical AND assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment).

From the MDN Web Docs:

```
let a = 1;
let b = 0;

a &&= 2;
console.log(a);
// expected output: 2

b &&= 2;
console.log(b);
// expected output: 0
```

Comment: But this operator also only depends on the value stored in the variable, not on the value that is to be assigned if I understand correctly.

Comment: This answer doesn't really address the issue. This only takes into consideration the left-hand side of the assignment. As explained in other comments, OP wants the assignment to take place if the **right-hand side** (i.e. the _new value_) is non-nullish.